# Selenium xpath - alternative of text() to locate an element using inner text?

Tags: python, selenium, xpath, selenium-webdriver

I am attempting to create a unique `XPATH` to select a checkbox using selenium in a table on a webpage.

The `HTML` looks like:

```
<tr ng-repeat="item in tests ">
   <td class="ng-binding">
       <span test: 'fa fa-cube greeniconcolor'}[item.type]"/>
       <span ng-show="item.type !='test' && item.type !='testset'">
       Test                 
      <div class="box-tools pull-right">
         <input type="checkbox" ng-model="selected_checkbox[$index]"/>
      </div>
   </td>
 </tr>
```

I would expect that I would be able to have an `XPATH` that looks like:

```
.//td[text()='Test']//input
```

to be able to click the checkbox, however that does not work. If I change it to contains and use the '.' notation instead of `text()` it does work:

```
.//td[contains(., 'Test')]//input
```

However if I do `.='Test'` it does not work. The reason I cannot use the `contains()` method is that the table also has `Test2` in it and that is also selected.

Any advice as to how come if I have other elements inside the `<tr>` tag I cannot use the `text()` method would be appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Any advice as to how come if I have other elements inside the tag I cannot use the text() method would be appreciated!

You should try using [`normalize-space()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Functions/normalize-space) function of `xpath` which is used to strips leading and trailing white-space from a string, replaces sequences of whitespace characters by a single space, and returns the resulting string as below :-

```
.//td[normalize-space(.)='Test']//input
```

Comment: Thanks! This was exactly what I needed